# Issues installing RcppArrayFire on Linux

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, arrayfire

I am trying to install the C++ library ArrayFire: https://arrayfire.com/

There is an R package for doing this: https://github.com/daqana/rcpparrayfire

However, I follow the instructions and install ArrayFire in my Downloads folder, then attempt installation as per the guide using:

`install.packages("RcppArrayFire", configure.args = "/home/enzo/Downloads/ArrayFire-3.9.0-Linux")`

However I get the following error:

`configure: error: Cannot find ArrayFire installation.`

However I can see the installation of ArrayFire in my Files in Downloads folder, and in the terminal it said the installation was successful, so i'm confused

Is there another way to install ArrayFire for use with R? I have installed header-only libraries before however this is not a header-only library so I don't think the process is the same?

Thanks!

Comment: That repo is, or was last I checked, unfortunately stale.  As I recall, I also failed the last time I tried.  It worked years ago but you may have to engage the excellent folls from ArrayFire about this.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel ! do you know if there a different way to install it? (or is it not that simple since it isnt header-only library?) if not i'll speak to them about it :)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have made a post on https://groups.google.com/g/arrayfire-users so hopefully get a reply. It doesnt seem very active but i'm not sure how else to contact them.

Comment: The documentation mentions to use `configure.args="--with-arrayfire=/opt/arrayfire"` but your question only contains the path. Copy-paste error or legitimate omission?

Comment: @Botje Sorry im confused isnt that the same thing as the path? (sorry if noob question)

Comment: `configure` is a program that takes arguments that start with two dashes. Behind the scenes your R package is calling `./configure /home/enzo....` while it should be `./configure --with-arrayfire=/home/enzo/...`

Comment: Hi @Botje, now I do:  ```  install_github("daqana/rcpparrayfire" , configure.args = "--with-arrayfire=/home/enzo/Downloads/arrayfire" )``` and it still dosnt work, says it cant find the ArrayFire installation....

Comment: @Botje Nevermind I worked it out! I had to move the installation to the /opt folder and rename the installation folder to "arrayfire". Basically it was ignoring the "configure.args" argument for some reason. Seems to have installed fine now.

Comment: @Botje So even though it installs it crashes R every time I try to run any function with a "read out of range" and "nul-terminator" errors.. I guess thats a separate issue though so i'll make a seperate post for it at some point.

Comment: I closed this now, the two questions by OP really are the same and due to struggles with the underlying ArrayFire installation which is a necessary requirement before contemplating combining it with Rcpp via RcppArrayFire.