# Difficulties in installing ArrayFire

Tags: arrayfire

I installed the RcppArrayFire R package ( via https://github.com/daqana/rcpparrayfire ) and I am trying to run the following simple example:

```r
#include <RcppArrayFire.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArrayFire)]]     
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp14)]]      
 
 
 // [[Rcpp::export]] 
 af::array                               AF_example_1( int n_rows,  
                                                       int n_cols) {   
   
   af::array  mat_AF =  af::constant(1, n_rows, n_cols)  ;  
   
   return(mat_AF);   
   
 }
```

It compiles fine, however I get the following error whenever I try to run it from R:

```r
ArrayFire Exception (Internal error:998):
In ../inst/include/RcppArrayFireWrap.h:46
Error: error in Arrayfire
```

Also I am compiling with the following flags:

```r
  Sys.setenv(CXX14FLAGS="-O3 -march=native -mtune=native -fPIC ")
  Sys.setenv(CXX_STD = "CXX14")  
  Sys.setenv(CXX14="/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/g++")
```

Is there something wrong with my code or compilation flags?

Thanks!

EDIT (note: reason for discrepancy between this info and info in comment is that i re-installed and downgraded OS for a different reason unrelated to this post) :

Session info:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 20

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/liblapack.so.3

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rstan_2.32.3        BH_1.81.0-1         StanHeaders_2.26.28 RcppEigen_0.3.3.9.4 Rcpp_1.0.11         RcppArrayFire_0.1.0 drat_0.2.4          githubinstall_0.2.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] QuickJSR_1.0.8     prettyunits_1.2.0  ps_1.7.5           utf8_1.2.4         digest_0.6.33      mime_0.12          R6_2.5.1           stats4_3.6.3       httr_1.4.7        
[10] ggplot2_3.4.4      pillar_1.9.0       rlang_1.1.2        curl_5.1.0         rstudioapi_0.15.0  data.table_1.14.8  miniUI_0.1.1.1     callr_3.7.3        urlchecker_1.0.1  
[19] devtools_2.4.5     stringr_1.5.1      loo_2.6.0          htmlwidgets_1.6.3  munsell_0.5.0      shiny_1.8.0        compiler_3.6.3     httpuv_1.6.12      pkgconfig_2.0.3   
[28] pkgbuild_1.4.2     htmltools_0.5.7    tibble_3.2.1       gridExtra_2.3      codetools_0.2-16   matrixStats_1.1.0  fansi_1.0.5        crayon_1.5.2       later_1.3.1       
[37] grid_3.6.3         jsonlite_1.8.7     xtable_1.8-4       gtable_0.3.4       lifecycle_1.0.4    magrittr_2.0.3     scales_1.2.1       RcppParallel_5.1.7 cli_3.6.1         
[46] stringi_1.8.2      cachem_1.0.8       fs_1.6.3           promises_1.2.1     remotes_2.4.2.1    ellipsis_0.3.2     vctrs_0.6.4        tools_3.6.3        glue_1.6.2        
[55] purrr_1.0.2        processx_3.8.2     pkgload_1.3.3      parallel_3.6.3     fastmap_1.1.1      inline_0.3.19      colorspace_2.1-0   sessioninfo_1.2.2  memoise_2.0.1     
[64] profvis_0.3.8      usethis_2.2.2     
>
```

```
> RcppArrayFire::arrayfire_info()


ArrayFire v3.8.0 (CUDA, 64-bit Linux, build d99887a)
Platform: CUDA Runtime 11.7, Driver: 515.43.04
[0] NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970, 4021 MB, CUDA Compute 5.2
```

```
> RcppArrayFire::arrayfire_device_info()
$name
[1] "NVIDIA_GeForce_GTX_970"

$platform
[1] "CUDA"

$toolkit
[1] "v11.7"

$compute
[1] "5.2"
```

OS: Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon

ArrayFire version: v3.8

I installed ArrayFire using the .sh installer found here:

https://arrayfire.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

using the following commands in the Linux terminal:

```
chmod +x arrayfire.sh
./arrayfire.sh
```

then, I had trouble installing using the `configure.args` argument to change the directory, i.e.:

```
  install_github("daqana/rcpparrayfire" , configure.args = "--with-arrayfire=/home/enzo/Downloads/arrayfire" )
```

So I moved the install directory to /opt:

```
sudo mv Downloads/arrayfire /opt/arrayfire
```

And then I could install RcppArrayFire using:

```
  require(drat)
  drat::addRepo("daqana")
  install.packages("RcppArrayFire"
```

EDIT 2:

If I change the variable type to f64 I get this error instead:

```
ArrayFire Exception (Internal error:998):
In function cuda::Module common::compileModule(const string&, const std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&, const std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&, const std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&, bool)
In file src/backend/cuda/compile_module.cpp:277
NVRTC Error(7): NVRTC_ERROR_BUILTIN_OPERATION_FAILURE
Log: 
nvrtc: error: failed to open libnvrtc-builtins.so.11.1.
  Make sure that libnvrtc-builtins.so.11.1 is installed correctly.

 0# 0x00007F6422281C3F in /opt/arrayfire/lib64/libafcuda.so.3
 1# 0x00007F64232AB84C in /opt/arrayfire/lib64/libafcuda.so.3
 2# 0x00007F642267BEF8 in /opt/arrayfire/lib64/libafcuda.so.3
 3# 0x00007F642267F77D in /opt/arrayfire/lib64/libafcuda.so.3
 4# 0x00007F6422680407 in /opt/arrayfire/lib64/libafcuda.so.3
 5# 0x00007F642221B72E in /opt/arrayfire/lib64/libafcuda.so.3
 6# 0x00007F6422309C3D in /opt/arrayfire/lib64/libafcuda.so.3
 7# af_get_data_ptr in /opt/arrayfire/lib64/libafcuda.so.3
 8# af_get_data_ptr in /opt/arrayfire/lib64/libaf
Error: error in Arrayfire
```

EDIT 3:

Sometimes (using the exact same program) I will instead get an aborted session message and I get the following error messages:

```
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.444822:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:86] read out of range
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.444856:ERROR elf_image_reader.cc:558] missing nul-terminator
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.444919:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.446864:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.446892:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.446912:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.446933:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.446952:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.446974:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447163:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447184:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447360:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447385:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447457:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447475:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447494:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447592:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447614:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447637:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447659:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447681:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447703:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447726:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447748:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447770:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447791:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447813:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447834:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447856:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447877:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447899:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447921:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447942:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447966:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.447990:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.448013:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42259:20231126,235559.448037:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[42259:42260:20231126,235559.473501:ERROR directory_reader_posix.cc:42] opendir: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Can you provide a bit more info: Which OS are you using? Which version of ArrayFire? How did you install it? What is the output of `RcppArrayFire::arrayfire_info()` and `RcppArrayFire::arrayfire_device_info()`?

Comment: Please add the session info / version info in a properly formatted way to your post. Nobody can decipher that in comments. As as I mentioned [yesterday to your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77543417/issues-installing-rcpparrayfire-on-linux#comment136704671_77543417) last time I tried it just bonked on me (whereas all this used to work).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks Il will edit the post. And there must be a way to get it to work as it works for Ralf

Comment: Hi @DirkEddelbuettel, how do I add the session info / version info in a proper format? I added the R version but not sure that's enough

Comment: The `sessionInfo()` function is your friend.

Comment: @RalfStubner Also if I do a void function (i.e. no return statement) then it runs fine.... not sure if thats important but it might give more of a hint as to whats causing the error

Comment: @E_1996 : I had another look at the ArrayFire github and it (good news!) seems to be more alive than the last time I checked and failed.  But ArrayFire and CUDA are somewhat demanding to install and instead of discussing this here with us (another thirdparty repository wholly dependent on ArrayFire and CUDA working) I *strongly* recommend you get ArrayFire itself sorted out.  Once you can compile and link one of their short examples (the docs are, overall, pretty good) you should then have no trouble installing and using RcppArrayFire.  Until then please ArrayFire folks for help.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel - i've never used C++ outside of Rcpp (is it simple?) hence me going straight to ArrayFire - i'll look into it as maybe its an ArrayFire issue per se rather than the RcppArrayFire package

Comment: Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu. Why are you setting `CXX14` to a compiler from devtoolset 8, something that one would normally do on CentOS/RHEL 7. Can you try without those compiler settings? Making sure that ArrayFire works independently of R as suggested by Dirk is a good idea, too.

Comment: @RalfStubner Thanks I changed the compiler location  - also if I change the af::array variable type to "f64" I get a different error which may be more informative (see "EDIT 2" in original post). I will try and run it independent of R too and see what happens, thanks

Comment: @RalfStubner I'm trying to run it directly from terminal now but it cant find "arrayfire.h" so I wonder if there was an issue with installation, but i re-installed and does the same thing. If I #include the entire path it then says it cant find "/af/defines.h", eventhough this is in the correct folder. I installed in /opt/.

Comment: @E_1996  As I said all this is 100% orthogonal to Rcpp.  Please just close possible delete this post.  Your troubles are due to a) not really being familiar with how one calls a compiler and linker and b) diving head first into a somewhat involved setup.  The saying is correct:  You need to learn "how to walk" before you can get into running.  I edited the Subject: and I will remove the Rcpp and R tags here.

Comment: Hi @DirkEddelbuettel I can run it from terminal just fine so I don't think its an installation issue? I can run the examples given here at the bottom of this page: https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/blob/master/docs/pages/install.md

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I got it working in the end on my laptop. Ended up installing Pop!_OS and works for me with CUDA v11.8 + ArrayFire v3.8.3. Following same steps on Linux Mint didnt work for me, unsure why.

Comment: Nice. I think it would be good if you could provide a short write up listening the parts.  I looked briefly on the weekend but my use of Ubuntu 23.10 (I update early and often) may conflict with some of the NVidia requirements for CUDA, sadly.